# Efficient way to perform rolling operations on tensor with Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, rolling-computation

I would like to write a function to perform some forward rolling operations over a tensor slice with PyTorch. Is there a way to do efficiently this?

For example, the RollingSum function should take a tensor and add up all values across the specified axis within the rolling slice/window.

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)
print(X)

tensor([[[1.]],
        [[2.]],
        [[3.]],
        [[4.]],
        [[5.]],
        [[4.]],
        [[3.]],
        [[2.]],
        [[1.]]])

def RollingSum(X, slice, axis):
    '''Return sum of a rolling slice on the tensor over a specified axis'''
    
    Xroll = _i_dont_know_how_to_do_this
    return Xroll


def RollingMax(X, slice, axis):
    '''Return max of a rolling slice on the tensor over a specified axis'''
    
    Xroll = _i_dont_know_how_to_do_this
    return Xroll


# Rolling sum
Xroll = RollingSum(X, slice=3, axis=0)
print(Xroll)
tensor([[[1.]],
        [[3.]],
        [[6.]],
        [[9.]],
        [[12.]],
        [[13.]],
        [[12.]],
        [[9.]],
        [[6.]]])

# Rolling max
Xroll = RollingMax(X, slice=3, axis=0)
print(Xroll)
tensor([[[1.]],
        [[2.]],
        [[3.]],
        [[4.]],
        [[5.]],
        [[5]],
        [[5.]],
        [[4.]],
        [[3.]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is useful mechanic in `PyTorch` for this, https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.unfold.html it creates tensor view, which allows to perform rolling as matrix axis-reducing operation:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]).reshape(1,1, -1)
X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)

def RollingOp(Op, X, slice, axis):
    '''Return sum of a rolling slice on the tensor over a specified axis'''
    PaddedX = torch.nn.functional.pad(X, ([0,0,]*axis + [slice-1,0]))
    XView = PaddedX.unfold( len(X.shape) -1-axis, slice, 1)
    Xroll =   Op(XView, dim=-1, )
    return Xroll

# Rolling sum
Xroll =     RollingOp( torch.sum, X,                     slice=3, axis=0 )
print(Xroll)
# Rolling another axis
Xroll =     RollingOp( torch.sum, X.reshape(1,-1,1),     slice=3, axis=1 )
print(Xroll)
# Rolling max
(Xroll,_) = RollingOp( torch.max, X,                     slice=3, axis=0 )
print(Xroll)
# 5d
(Xroll,_) = RollingOp( torch.max, X.reshape(1,1,-1,1,1), slice=2, axis=2 )
print(Xroll)
```

tensor([[[ 1.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 13., 12.,  9.,  6.]]])
tensor([[[ 1.],
[ 3.],
[ 6.],
[ 9.],
[12.],
[13.],
[12.],
[ 9.],
[ 6.]]])
tensor([[[1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 5., 5., 4., 3.]]])
tensor([[[[[0.]],
[[1.]],
[[2.]],
[[3.]],
[[4.]],
[[5.]],
[[5.]],
[[4.]],
[[3.]],
[[2.]]]]])

See also: [How can I resize a PyTorch tensor with a sliding window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157188/how-can-i-resize-a-pytorch-tensor-with-a-sliding-window)

---

EDITED 1,2: Bugfix